# Why does UmbrellaException have that name?

Tags: java, exception, gwt

I'm working with GWT and sometimes I'm getting exception called [UmbrellaException](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/UmbrellaException.html)
I was always wondering why is it called like that? It is because there is a lot of error (rain) that you have to protect the application (use umbrella not to get wet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the first link when i googled the term "gwt umbrellaexception":

> A `RuntimeException` that collects a `Set` of child `Throwable` together.
>       Typically thrown after loop, with all of the exceptions thrown during that loop,
>       but delayed so that the loop finishes executing.

It's just a `Collection` of `Exception` (`Throwable` actually). [Read the API Doc for more information](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/UmbrellaException.html).

Comment: The name comes from a different use of the word 'umbrella' meaning an object that covers a variety of things.  Buying 'umbrella' insurance can cover house, car, etc.  In this case, it's an exception that covers multiple other exceptions.

Comment: I guess that is the answer he asked for :) +1

Comment: Yeah... that's what i was looking for. Technically I know what it does i just wanted to get a concept why they named it like that. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas, you could post an answer with the explanation you gave us, that's actually the right answer :) I don't mind if Maksim changes the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

> A RuntimeException that collects a Set of child Throwables together. Typically thrown after loop, with all of the exceptions thrown during that loop, but delayed so that the loop finishes executing.

[com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/event/shared/UmbrellaException.html)

It's a `Set` of all the exceptions thrown during a loop which is thrown after the loop is done. Looks like it's used to let the loop to finish even if some exceptions occur during it's execution.